# lvcreate vg0 not found

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, mongodb

I am looking at the mongodb documentation for creating a logical volume with lvcreate.

```
lvcreate --size 100M --snapshot --name mdb-snap01 /dev/vg0/mongodb
```

The example is the output is:

> Using default stripesize 64.00 KiB.   Volume group "vg0" not found
>   Cannot process volume group vg0

I made my research here and with google, and I found no explanation for this.
I also had to run this as a super user.

Comment: I tried to create a directory and touch file but I didn't have permissions even as sudo

Comment: Why do you think you have a VG named "vg0"?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams    
I don't. I need to create one on my virtual host drive. Is that possible to allocate a few GB for this?